# ansible local_action returns error "invalid output was: [sudo via ansible, key=xxx] password:"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've being trying to run this ansible playbook to get a AWS resource tags:

`- name: list resource tags
  local_action: ec2_tag resource=i-abcdefg region=us-east-1 state=list
  register: result`

And this error is returned:

> failed: [ec2-11-222-333-444.compute-1.amazonaws.com] => {"failed":
>   true, "parsed": false} invalid output was: [sudo via ansible,
>   key=heoqwlqnhxlxyzwnxmtbvmdtvmvjbsux] password:
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

How can I fix that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot run this local_action as root. Change your task to be:

`- name: list resource tags
  sudo: false
  local_action: ec2_tag resource=i-abcdefg region=us-east-1 state=list
  register: result`

Comment: Any idea why this is?

Comment: Perhaps because it would require a password and ansible cannot provide it.